# Associative binary operation with several left inverse elememts

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, semigroups, binary-operations, associativity

I am supposed to find a binary operation that is associative and has several left inverse elements. I have no clue how to do that or if it is even possible, please help :)

Comment: How about the set of all functions $f:\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$ with the operation of composition?

Comment: I guess the operation should have a (two-sided) identity element, so that "left inverse" is meaningful. Now, you just need there to be at least one element with several left inverses, right? Because of course the identity element will have only one left inverse, namely itself. And there will have to be some element with no left inverse at all, because if every element has at least one left inverse, then you've got a group and the inverses are unique.

Comment: Correctly stated, you probably want an operation for which **some element** has several left inverses; to say that "the operation has several left inverses" is meaningless. (And indeed as mentioned by bof, you need the existence of a unit, so the question is to find a monoid for which some element has at least two left inverses.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the monoid presented by $\langle a, b, c \mid ac = bc = 1 \rangle$. Then $a$ and $b$ are both left inverses of $c$. Note that such an example has to be an infinite monoid. Indeed, in a finite monoid, the condition $xz= yz = 1$ implies $x = y$.